# Remove Focus/Blur on Select programmatically (Angular6 Material)

Tags: angular

I duplicated the Angular 6 Material autocomplete simple example:
[Simple Autocomplete](https://stackblitz.com/angular/brrjvqvprrbv?file=app%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.ts)

I am trying to figure out how remove focus once selection has been made.

I have added the following change:

In HTML

```
<mat-autocomplete #autoGroup="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelectionChanged($event)">
```

In Components

```
  onSelectionChanged(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
    console.log(event.option.value);
  }
```

After it outputs the value  to console i would like to remove the focus from the input field, but not sure the way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the `mat-focused` class of mat-form-field causes the focus on mat-auto-complete, by removing it from mat-form-field it will be not focused,

**in component**:

```
export class AutocompleteSimpleExample {
  myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  public matForm ;
  constructor(){

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.matForm =  document.getElementById("matForm") 
  }
  options = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three'
   ];

  test(option){
    console.log(option)
    setTimeout(function(){
      this.matForm.classList.remove('mat-focused' )}, 100);
  }
}
```

**in html**:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width test" #matForm id="matForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" #textInput>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="test($event.option)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{ option }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zi4ofc).

**Building on answer as per Aeseir's findings**

Link @ViewChild to your input.

```
export class WhateverComponent {
@ViewChild('textInput') textInput: ElementRef;
//all other code
}
```

in onSelectionChanged function

```
onSelectionChanged(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
    console.log(event.option.value);
    // blur will remove focus on the currently selected element
    this.matInputMain.nativeElement.blur();
    // if you using form you can wipe the input too
    this.yourForm.reset();        
  }
```

The above will log the selected value to console, blur the focus and reset the form (if you using form and want this function).

Comment: @aeseir did you check the answer? no comment?

Comment: sorry been on holidays, i used your answer as inspiration to find the angular way. Do you want me to update your to reflect what i found?

Comment: @Aeseir yes ofcourse, i also found to set blur() for input, but would be good if you share your answer.

Comment: check out my edit, if you want create a stackblitz for it too. I think there is a better way to do this tho, an even more angular way, something is not adding up.

Comment: Accepted answer. I tried finding some alternative but no luck. I think it might be there under material umbrella but they need to document it

Comment: what is `this.matInputMain`? where did it come from?

Comment: @Vali D I think it should be this.textInput

Answer (score 4):

My autocomplete field works with this typescript function

```
public removeFocus(field, input){
   field._elementRef.nativeElement.classList.remove('mat-focused');
   input.blur(); 
}
```

HTML code

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width test" #autocompleteField>
   <input matInput type="text" 
     placeholder="Pick one" 
     aria-label="Number"  
     [formControl]="myControl" 
     [matAutocomplete]="auto" 
     #elementInput
   >
   <mat-autocomplete 
    #auto="matAutocomplete" 
    (optionSelected)="removeFocus(autocompleteField, elementInput)">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
      {{ option }}
     </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Remove focus from both the mat-form-field and its input.

Comment: I prefer your answer to the accepted answer since it doesn't use timeouts and doesn't use `document.getElementById`. Think this is much cleaner and less error-prone.

Comment: worked like a charm and saved my day. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try this
**Template**

```
<input #autoCompleteInput type="text" [matAutocomplete]="auto"/>
```

**component**

```
@ViewChild('autoCompleteInput', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger }) autoComplete: MatAutocompleteTrigger;

  close() {
    this.autoComplete.closePanel();
  }
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/p6HbA5KeNnUzL0ZXA3AY?p=preview)

Comment: in Angular 8(+ probably), this closes the autocomplete panel, but does not remove the textfield's focus.

Answer (score -1):

An even nicer solution to removing focus on the autocomplete parent input if it is a mat-input, is to reference it using `@ViewChild` as `MatInput`. `MatInput` has a public field `focused` which can be set to `false`:

```
@ViewChild('searchInput', { static: false }) private searchInput: MatInput;
// some time later...
this.searchInput.focused = false
```